Is there a workaround for npx concurrently replacing stdout with a socket on Linux?
There's a Nodejs utility, concurrently, which can be used to execute several commands at once, and it prefixes each one's output with a tag. For example:
npx concurrently -n "frontend,backend" "launch_frontend.sh" "launch_backend.sh"

When used on Linux, stdout of the children point to a socket, whereas on Macos stdout remains file descriptor 1.
This means that the following command succeeds on Macos, but fails on Linux:
npx concurrently "echo 'hello world' > /dev/stdout"
However this command succeeds on both:
echo 'hello world' > /dev/stdout
Under concurrently on Linux /dev/stdout points to /proc/self/fd/1 which points to socket:[12345] rather than the usual /dev/pts/0 or similar.
So my problem is:
I have something I want to run, via npx concurrently, but that thing tries to open /dev/stdout. It works on Macos, but fails for users on Linux.
Given that I can't easily modify the thing that is run, is there another way to around around this issue on Linux?
I have found one workaround, but it comes with some negatives. This is passing the --raw flag to concurrently. However as the name implies, it prevents the nice log processing that would otherwise occur.

Try using --raw. Otherwise, it tries to add color to the output, so it needs to redirect stdout to a socket or pipe so it can intercede.

See all the options related to prefix styling. How do you expect it to do any of that if the output is just sent directly to the terminal?

I noted that I had tried --raw in my original post. Also note that the prefix styling works fine with /dev/stdout on Macos - it's only on Linux that things are broken, due to the change to a socket.

There may be OS-specific features on MacOS that don't exist on Linux, so it needs to use the socket.

However, I'm not sure why connecting stdout to a socket actually causes problems. Presumably concurrently is reading from the other end of the socket.

And why is this a programming problem? You seem to be a user of this utility, not programming it.

In some ways, the problem is that software opening /dev/stdout expects it to point to a filehandle, not a socket reference, and so it seems fopen() etc fail.

Fundamentally, my question is about understanding how to navigate the situation when that arises -- /dev/stdout being a symlink to a "socket:[port]" (which I didn't even know was really possible previously). If that's not about programming, then I'm sorry. But hey, help a fellow out anyway?

I actually don't know why that's happening or what you're supposed to do about it. Writing to /dev/stdout is supposed to be the same as writing to stdout itself. The symlink target is synthesized for human information, it's not required to be a real pathname (since sockets don't have to be in the filesystem).

This is probably a socket created by socketpair().
